# Why do mysterious newline characters randomly appear during IPython sessions?

Tags: python, powershell, ipython, powershell-core, windows-terminal

## Problem

Newline characters randomly appear in my terminal window if I've had an IPython session running for more than a few minutes.

### Screenshots/diagram

[image: Diagram of the problem]

---

### Context

#### OS:

```
Edition Windows 11 Enterprise
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎3/‎7/‎2022
OS build    22000.708
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.708.0
```

The problem also occurred when I was using `Windows 10`.

#### Terminal info:

```
Windows Terminal Preview
Version: 1.14.1452.0
Profile: PowerShell Core, version: 7.2.4
```

...though I've had the problem occur on other `Windows Terminal` versions as well as other versions of `PowerShell`.

#### Python info:

- `Python 3.8.10 (default, May 19 2021, 13:12:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`
- `matplotlib 3.4.3`

#### Other details:

This seems to only happen when `matplotlib` has been used, namely when a plot has been instantiated. I'm using the `Qt5Agg` backend.

Please let me know if any further info is needed. Thanks in advance!